# VS Webtest: How to use extracted value from request in Webtest loop count?

Tags: visual-studio, loops, performance-testing, load-testing, webtest

I have two extracted values (count and count1) -> these should be integers. I need to subtract (count1 - count = difference) and use the difference in a loop of webtest (delete generated groups).

How can I pass this result to Webtest loop (iteration) count?

http://hmp.me/pz0 
http://hmp.me/pz2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might create a web test request plugin, give it three parameters (ie properties) two are the `count1` and `count2` context parameters. The plugin does a subtraction and stores the result into a third context parameter (named via the third property). Then just use the value in the third context parameter in the loop condition.

The input context parameters will contain strings that will need to be converted to integers (or floats or whatever your application needs). The result will need to be converted back to a string before saving.

The plugin could be as follows. Note: not compiled or tested. Note: same code could also be done in a `PreRequest` or a `PreRequestDataBinding` plugin.

```
public class SubtractContextParameters : WebTestRequestPlugin
{
    public string LeftHandNumberCP { get; set; }
    public string RightHandnumberCP { get; set; }
    public string ResultCP { get; set; }

    public override void PostRequest(object sender, PostRequestEventArgs e)
    {
        int left = int.Parse(e.WebTest.Context[LeftHandNumberCP].ToString());
        int right = int.Parse(e.WebTest.Context[RightHandnumberCP].ToString());        
        int result = left - right;        
        e.WebTest.Context[ResultCP] = result.ToString();
    }
}
```

The name passed to the `ResultCP` property could then be used in a `NumberComparison` condition in the web test loop.